# Can session be shared between two different applications hosted in separate application servers

Tags: java, session, web-applications, jboss, weblogic

I am curious to know if this is possible:

## Physical Server A:

Hosts web application A in weblogic application server.

## Physical server B:

Hosts portet P, in JBOSS application server.

Now, in web application A, I am creating some XML file. Can i place the XML file in session and pass it to portlet P hosted in Physical sever B.

Like, in web-app "A" have a link for portlet-P (hosted in physical server-B), so while clicking on the link, it redirects to portlet-P, and sends the data to P. Now, can we have session that can be "transferred" from web-application A, to portlet P?

If this isn't achievable, then are there any other alternatives, please suggest.

Best Regards

Comment: Why do you want to share the session? to authenticate?

Comment: For passing the user info; and the xml data.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to share session directly between two applications, because the cookie set by `www.abc.com/app1` will not be sent to `www.abc.com/app2`.

But you when you have a session on server1, you can send the required details to server2 and create a session. So that you will have same session on both servers.